# Design patterns for creating objects that have a list of objects that also have a list of objects

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, class-design

In terms of good OOP design, what is the best way to structure code that is just containers of list of objects that contains other lists of objects that also are just other containers?

Example: A Cookbook owns a list of Chapters that owns a list of Recipes that owns  a list of Directions. Each object is a different layer within a whole. For clarity, I use the word "list" to refer to any data structure used to store multiple objects.

I've come across this Russian doll problem of nested objects inside of nested objects many times. I've tried passing the bottom level objects through the nest hierarchy and also tried writing methods that pass information down to the bottom nested object. My structure always feels messy because the intermediate classes are filled with methods that do nothing more than passing either objects or information.

An addition due to confusion expressed in the comments:
I'm looking for direction in things to study for handling a general type of problem. I'm not asking for a solution to a specific coding problem that I have in front of me. I wasn't expecting a "one answer to rule them all", but more of "use A design pattern for X situations but use B design pattern for Y situations and beware of Z." The example is for providing a general context, not a specific one.

Comment: It seems strange to me that a Menu object would have as its grand-children, Ingredient objects. OOP is supposed to be a model for real-world thinking, so when was the last time you saw a menu where all the dishes listed all of their ingredients? Perhaps try something like the Menu object holding DishSummary items, and a helper class can take a DishSummary object and return a DishDetail object (with Ingredients), if needed

Comment: @Graham I OP is not disclosing the real domain his code is applied to and that the menu example is just that, an example.

Comment: Are you talking about a scenario where the top level object *owns* all the nested objects, or merely has references to them?  As @Graham says, it doesn't make much sense for a `Menu` to own all the `Ingredient`s.  Is there also a `Cookbook` in your hypothetical scenario?

Comment: Yes, the example is just an example. It wasn't intended to be the actual problem. Maybe a better example would be a `Cookbook` owns `Chapters` that owns `Recipes` that owns `Directions`. Each object is a different layer within a whole.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this is an example of a domain, but that's not the point. The top-level object (Menu in the example) does not need to know anything about the lower-level details (the Ingredients), so having it be the parent object of those details is potentially a sign of a poor design. Following that pattern to the end, every object would live under a top-level Company/Restaurant object.

Comment: @Graham I've changed the example in the hopes that it will better express the issue I'm trying to address.

Comment: You ask how to avoid a Russian doll problem, while intentionally structuring your code as a Russian doll. Just stop doing that. OOP classes can be modeled after real-world objects when that helps improve your codebase, but you are not constrained by that. Does every section of your app that needs CookBook info also need every Direction detail of every Recipe inside each of them? If not, then compose structures for just the details that the application section needs at that time, like `CookBookSummary` (name, id, price, etc).

Comment: I am curios, which programming language are you using primarily?

Comment: @DocBrown I'm primarily using Java. Just to make it clear, I wasn't trying to address a specific problem but a general one. I'm in my last semester at university and wanting to better understand how to structure code.

Comment: Unclear for me what the problem is. It's like asking "what's the best way to create russian dolls but without directly creating russian dolls".

Comment: @WP0987: you might consider to add a small code example to demonstrate your problem - from a description like "it always feels messy" it is not really clear where the problem is.

Comment: @DocBrown I think I've misunderstood the difference between "stackoverflow" and "programmers". I had thought that "programmers" was a little more open to discussion. I was looking for direction in what to study to solve a particular (but not an exact specific) type of problem. I learned a lot from both examples presented and now know more about when to use one instead of the other because of the thesis then antithesis statements leading to a more complete synthesis. Next time I'll go to a forum for questions like the one I posted and only post specific code problems here.

Comment: @WP0987: for discussions, you are welcome to try [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). The SE sites, however, are not discussion forums, they are Q&A sites. Here on "Programmers", we try to find the best possible answer to conceptual programming questions. The best questions are those for *actual, real problems* people have. Questions which only lead to open ended discussions with no possibility of finding a "best" answer are typically closed by the community here.

Comment: ... said that, your question still looks like you have an actual problem to solve - or at least you had that problem in the past, in *real code* you had written. So if you want a feedback on this, you could either post it here or, if it goes deep into code details, you could also try codereview.stackexchange

Comment: .. finally, your wrote you were *"looking for direction in things to study for handling a general type of problem"* - that is fine, but the general type of problem you described looks still to be a bad fit for the composite pattern, and a much better fit for explicit OO modeling.

Comment: [*Head First Design Patterns*](https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Design-Patterns-Freeman/dp/0596007124). This book does compare and contrast between design patterns. And I like the teaching style of the *Head Start* books in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make it easier is that all classes implement the same interface so you can treat them indistinctly. Theres a [known pattern for this](http://www.mcdonaldland.info/files/designpatterns/designpatternscard.pdf):

[image]

The good news is that as this creates a tree. You can then write, in an external managing class, recursive methods to look up items.

For example you could write a method `findAndAdd(String tagToFind, Component componentToAdd);`

To the base interfaces documented in the pattern you should add a `tagMatches(String tag)` as well as all common getters and setters so you can, again, treat items indistincltly of their class.

I would add `hasChild()` and `nextChild()` methods to implement iterations.

Comment: Is `i` just an index to the `(i-1)ᵗʰ` item (for zero-based arrays)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I guess that it so. That UML diagram is just an example, I would add hasChild() and nextChild() methods to implement iterations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey although the internal implementation of the list must be dynamic to allow for adding new items, like the List interface in Java.

Comment: -1, abusing the composite pattern for a fixed hierarchy of *different* levels of non recursive structured objects is nothing but an example of overengineering.

Comment: @DocBrown What should be used instead of the composite pattern? It's better to light a candle . . .

Comment: @WP0987: see my answer below. You are IMHO approaching this from the wrong side, your data structure is probably ok, instead you may consider to implement the code which accesses it differently.

Comment: This reminds me of navigation the DOM of an HTML or XML Document - sort of "jQuery-ish".  Interesting idea, if it is something you can apply to many *other* lists of lists of lists in your code.

Comment: @user949300: navigation in DOM in HTML or XML is typically achieved using `xpath`, not specifically to jQuery. But this is exactly my point: the problem the OP described has probably nothing to do with the underlying data structure, but with the way he queries the data.

Comment: And **if** all the objects in the hierarchy have different capabilities (ie different methods) ? It would mean you either have to declare all of them in the interface, leading to unimplemented methods in some classes (code smell) or declare them in their respective classes but since you unified the whole hierarchy under one interface they are not directly visible. So you'll have to crazy-cast everywhere to reach these methods (again, bigger code smell). That's how a design pattern becomes an anti-pattern...

Comment: @Spotted I'm pretty sure all elements are basically a node with a description and a list. Besides some properties can be reached with getProperty(String propertyName) like in HMTML. Besides getChapters() ad getRecipes() are basically getChildren();. Also OP's main problem was not casting different types because all types are basically lists containing lists, his main problem is how to populate the lists and pass info down the hierarchy.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Yep, that's why I said "if" because it's not sure at the moment that my comment above is relevant (at least as long as the OP doesn't provide more details).

Answer (score 17):

Do yourself a favor, and **keep it simple and stupid!**

In your example, you wanted to model `Cookbooks`, having `Chapters`, containing `Recipes`, owning `Directions`". In terms of good OO design, you model exactly this: a class `Cookbook` with an aggregate list of `Chapters`, having an aggregate list of `Recipes`, each one with a list of `Directions`. This is a straightforward mapping from "real world objects" to "OOP objects", which is one of the core ideas of object oriented modeling. It is easy to understand and maintain for you and anyone else who has to deal with this data.

At this point, your code is not yet messy. It might become messy if you often have to write methods like

```
 // inside a Cookbook method:
 foreach chapter in listChapters
     foreach recipe in  chapter.listRecipes
          foreach  direction in  recipe.listDirection
              // do something with direction
```

You can avoid writing such code more than once if your programming language has good support for creating your own iterator function (like C# or Python). Then you can easily provide resuable helper functions once for getting, for example, all directions in a cookbook. Another approach it to utilize the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), it will allow you to provide different operations "visiting" all objects in that hierarchy and do "something" during the visit.

Of course, when you have *uniform* containers, where on each level of the hierarchy a container can hold a list of containers of *the same type*, then the composite pattern suggested in @TulainsCórdova answer makes sense. Examples for this are a file/folder hierarchy, or a tree structure for abstract syntax trees, where expressions contain subexpressions which contain subexpressions, and so on. But in your example, each of the container object you described on each level is different from each object on another level, it has a different name, probably a different behaviour, and contains only sub containers of one specific type. So trying to shoehorn the described case into the composite pattern will probably make your code really messy.

Comment: Needs more details:  could you please elaborate on how you think the helper functions might look?  Mainly, does Cookbook know about ingredients, or only about recipes?  How to navigate the layers?

Comment: @user949300: it would be helpful if the OP would give an understandable example where his code "becomes messy" (as he wrote), then I could probably tell him how to tailor an iterator for this. But so far the ony response I see that he accepted a clearly overengineered answer which does not really fit to his question in favor of mine. So I have to assume I might not have understood his intentions correctly.