# What would be the disadvantage to defining a class as a subclass of a list of itself?

Tags: java, class-design, list, subclassing

In a recent project of mine, I defined a class with the following header:

```java
public class Node extends ArrayList<Node> {
    ...
}
```

However, after discussing with my CS professor, he stated that the class would both be "horrible for memory" and "bad practice". I have not found the first to be particularly true, and the second to be subjective.

My reasoning for this usage is that I had an idea for an object which needed to be defined as something that could have arbitrary depth, where the behavior of an instance could be defined either by a custom implementation or by the behavior of several like objects interacting. This would allow for the abstraction of objects whose physical implementation would be made up of many sub-components interacting.¹

On the other hand, I see how this could be bad practice. The idea of defining something as a list of itself is not simple or physically implementable.

Is there any valid reason why I *shouldn't* use this in my code, considering my use for it?

---

¹ If I need to explain this further, I would be glad to; I am just attempting to keep this question concise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Design patterns for creating objects that have a list of objects that also have a list of objects](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330330/design-patterns-for-creating-objects-that-have-a-list-of-objects-that-also-have)

Comment: @gnat This has more to do with strictly defining a class as a list of itself, rather than containing lists which contain lists. I think it's a variant of a similar thing, but not entirely the same. That question refers to something along the lines of [Robert Harvey's answer](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335213/218643).

Comment: If a node was a list of nodes and leaves (and leaves were not nodes) would you use multiple inheritance?

Comment: @immibis Instances of my class may only have list members who are of my class.

Comment: Inherit from something that is parameterized by itself is not unusual, as shows the commonly used [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) idiom in C++.  In the case of the container, the key question is however to justify why you have to use inheritance instead of composition.

Comment: @Christophe: However, I don't really see the need for F-bounded Polymorphism here.

Comment: @coredump Empty array lists with methods returning values. They aren't just simple subclasses, there's extra implementation there.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree. My comment referred more to the general problem of inheriting from something based on itself, than to the specific case of the list (especially in view of the additional infos provided).

Comment: I think there's a section on this in the Effective Java book. I'll look it up when I get back home for a more better/accurate.

Comment: This doesn't achieve "arbitrary depth." It may achieve "arbitrary *breadth*".

Comment: I like the idea. After all, each node in a tree *is a* (sub) tree. Usually the tree-ness of a node is concealed from a type view (the classical node is not a tree but a single object) and instead expressed in the data view (the single node allows access to branches). Here it's the other way around; we won't see branch data, it's in the type. Ironically, the actual object layout in C++ would likely be very similar (inheritance is implemented very similarly to containing data), which makes me think we are dealing with two ways expressing the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I am missing a bit, but do you really need to _extend_ `ArrayList<Node>`, compared to _implement_ `List<Node>`?

Comment: @Matthias This represents my actual implementation so far - this is the very early stages of this project, and, were I continue with this path, I would likely change from an extension of ArrayList to an implementation of List.

Comment: The reference I was looking for is Item 16 (Effective Java by Joshua Bloch), which uses inheriting a collection as an example.

Answer (score 107):

Frankly, I don't see the need for inheritance here.  It doesn't make sense; `Node` ***is an*** `ArrayList` of `Node`?

If this is just a recursive data structure, you would simply write something like:

```
public class Node {
    public String item;
    public List<Node> children;
}
```

Which *does* make sense; node ***has a*** list of children or descendant nodes.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is the same thing, except you would have to define a method to get the members of Children (or return the List in some getter method).

Comment: It's not the same thing.  A list of a list of a list *ad-infinitum* is meaningless unless you are storing *something* besides a new list in the list.  That's what `Item`  is there for, and `Item` operates independently of the lists.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I had approached `Node` ***is an*** `ArrayList` of `Node` as `Node` ***contains 0 to many*** `Node` objects. Their function is the same, essentially, but instead of _being_ a list of like objects, it _has_ a list of like objects. The original design for the class written was the belief that any `Node` can be expressed as a set of sub`Node`s, which both implementation do, but this one is certainly less confusing. +1

Comment: I would say that identity between a node and a list tends to arise "naturally" when you write singly-linked lists in C or Lisp or whatever: in certain designs the head node "is" the list, in the sense of being the only thing ever used to represent a list. So I can't completely dispel the feeling that in some contexts perhaps a node "is" (not just "has") a collection of nodes, even though I agree it feels EvilBadWrong in Java.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So still, how is this different from `public class Node extends ArrayList<Node> { public string Item; }` ? I find it is easier to use `someNode[2][3][5].Item` than it is to use `someNode.Children[2].Children[3].Children[5].Item`

Comment: @nl-x Well, in C# you can put in an indexer and still have that syntax.  That indexer would work with any collection, not just an array.  But yes, I could see how that might be useful in Java.

Comment: @nl-x That the one syntax is shorter doesn't mean it's better.  Also, incidentally, it's pretty rare to access items in a tree like that.  Usually the structure isn't known at compile time, so you tend to not be traversing such trees by constant values.  The depth is also not fixed, so you can't even iterate over all values using that syntax.  When you adapt the code to use a traditional tree traversal problem you end up writing `Children` just once or twice, and it's typically *preferable* to write it out in such cases for the sake of code clarity.

Comment: +1 for [**Favouring composition over inheritance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Also, if you really wanted your Node to be iterable like a list, you can still use this approach and just declare it as `implements List<Node>` (or even `Collection<Node>` if you don't need the full List interface) then implement the List (or Collection) interface methods to just delegate to the same methods in the encapsulated ArrayList.

Comment: @daiscog Or just implement Iterable<Node>.  I think would be prefereable here.

Answer (score 58):

The “horrible for memory” argument is entirely wrong, but it is an *objectively* “bad practice”. When you inherit from a class, you don't just inherit the fields and methods you are interested in. Instead, you inherit *everything*. Every method that it declares, even if it isn't useful for you. And most importantly, you also inherit all its contracts and guarantees that the class provides.

The acronym SOLID provides some heuristics for good object-oriented design. Here, the ***I***nterface Segregation Principle (ISP) and the ***L***iskov Substitution Pricinple (LSP) have something to say.

The ISP tells us to keep our interfaces as small as possible. But by inheriting from `ArrayList`, you get many, many methods. Is it meaningful to `get()`, `remove()`, `set()` (replace), or `add()` (insert) a child node at a particular index? Is it sensible to `ensureCapacity()` of the underlying list? What does it mean to `sort()` a Node? Are users of your class really supposed to get a `subList()`? Since you cannot hide methods you don't want, the only solution is to have the ArrayList as a member variable, and forward all methods that you actually want:

```
private final ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList();
public void add(Node child) { children.add(child); }
public Iterator<Node> iterator() { return children.iterator(); }
```

If you really want all the methods you see in the documentation, we can move on to the LSP. The LSP tells us that we must be able to use the subclass wherever the parent class is expected. If a function takes an `ArrayList` as parameter and we pass our `Node` instead, nothing is supposed to change.

Compatibility of subclasses starts with simple things like type signatures. When you override a method, you can't make the parameter types more strict since that might exclude uses that were legal with the parent class. But that is something the compiler checks for us in Java.

But the LSP runs much deeper: We have to maintain compatibility with everything that is promised by the documentation of all parent classes and interfaces. In [their answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335263/), Lynn has found one such case where the `List` interface (which you have inherited via `ArrayList`) guarantees how the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are supposed to work. For `hashCode()` you are even given a particular algorithm that must be implemented exactly. Let's assume you have written this `Node`:

```
public class Node extends ArrayList<Node> {
  public final int value;

  public Node(int value, Node... children) {
    this.value = Value;
    for (Node child : children)
      add(child);
  }

  ...

}
```

This requires that the `value` cannot contribute to the `hashCode()` and cannot influence `equals()`. The `List` interface – which you promise to honour by inheriting from it – requires `new Node(0).equals(new Node(123))` to be true.

---

Because inheriting from classes makes it too easy to accidentally break a promise that a parent class made, and because it usually exposes more methods than you intended, it is generally suggested that you **prefer composition over inheritance**. If you must inherit something, it is suggested to only inherit interfaces. If you want to reuse behaviour of a particular class, you can keep it as a separate object in an instance variable, that way all its promises and requirements aren't forced on you.

Sometimes, our natural language suggests an inheritance relationship: A car is a vehicle. A motorcycle is a vehicle. Should I define classes `Car` and `Motorcycle` that inherit from a `Vehicle` class? Object-oriented design is not about mirroring the real world exactly in our code. We cannot easily encode the rich taxonomies of the real world in our source code.

One such example is the employee-boss modelling problem. We have multiple `Person`s, each with a name and address. An `Employee` is a `Person` and has a `Boss`. A `Boss` is also a `Person`. So should I create a `Person` class that is inherited by `Boss` and `Employee`? Now I have a problem: the boss is also an employee and has another superior. So it seems like `Boss` should extend `Employee`. But the `CompanyOwner` is a `Boss` but isn't an `Employee`? Any kind of inheritance graph will somehow break down here.

OOP isn't about hierarchies, inheritance, and re-use of existing classes, it is about *generalizing behaviour*. OOP is about “I have a bunch of objects and want them to do a particular thing – and I don't care how.” That's what *interfaces* are for. If you implement the `Iterable` interface for your `Node` because you want to make it iterable, that's perfectly fine. If you implement the `Collection` interface because you want to add/remove child nodes etc., then that's fine. But inheriting from another class because it happens to give you all that is not, or at least not unless you have given it careful thought as outlined above.

Comment: I've printed your last 4 paragraphs, titled them as _About OOP and Inheritance_ and pined them on the wall at work. Some of my colleagues need to see that as I know they would appreciate the way you put it :) Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Extending a container in as of itself is usually accepted to be bad practice. There's really very little reason to extend a container instead of just having one. Extending a container of yourself just makes it extra strange.

Answer (score 14):

Adding to what has been said, there is a somewhat Java-specific reason to avoid this kind of structures.

The contract of the `equals` method for lists requires a list to be considered equal to another object

> if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Specifically, this means that having a class designed as a list of itself may make equality comparisons expensive (and hash calculations as well if the lists are mutable), and if the class has some instance fields, well these *must* be ignored in the equality comparison.

Comment: This is an excellent reason to remove this from my code aside of bad practice. :P

Answer (score 3):

### Regarding memory:

I'd say this is a matter of perfectionism. The default-constructor of `ArrayList` looks like this:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
     super();

     if (initialCapacity < 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+ initialCapacity);

     this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
 }

public ArrayList() {
     this(10);
}
```

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java). This constructor is also used in the Oracle-JDK.

Now consider constructing a singly-linked List with your code. You've just successfully bloated your memory-consumption by the factor 10x (to be precise even marginally higher). For trees this can easily get pretty bad as well without any special requirements on the structure of the tree. Using a `LinkedList` or other class alternatively should solve this issue.

To be honest, in most cases this is nothing but mere perfectionism, even if we ignore the amount of available memory. A `LinkedList` would slow down the code a bit as an alternative, so it's a trade-off between performance and memory-consumption either way. Still my personal opinion on this would be to not waste that much memory in way that can be as easily circumvented as this one.

EDIT: clarification regarding the comments (@amon to be precise). This section of the answer does **not** deal with the issue of inheritance. The comparison of memory usage is made against a singly-linked List and with best memory-usage (in actual implementations the factor might change a bit, but it's still sufficiently large to sum up to quite a bit of wasted memory).

### Regarding "Bad practice":

Definitely. This is not the standard-way of implementing a graph for a simple reason: A Graph-Node **has** child-nodes, not **it is** as list of child-nodes. Precisely expressing what you mean in code is a major skill. Be it in variable-names or expressing structures like this one. Next point: keeping interfaces minimal: You've made every method of `ArrayList` available to the user of the class via inheritance. There's no way to alter this without breaking the entire structure of the code. Instead store the `List` as internal variable and make required methods available via an adapter-method. This way you can easily add and remove functionality from the class without messing everything up.

Comment: 10x higher compared to *what*? If I have a default-constructed ArrayList as an instance field (instead of inheriting from it), I'm actually using slightly more memory since I need to store an additional pointer-to-ArrayList in my object. Even if we are comparing apples with oranges and compare inheriting from ArrayList to not using any ArrayList, note that in Java we always deal with pointers to objects, never objects by value as C++ would do. Assuming an `new Object[0]` uses 4 words total, a `new Object[10]` would only use 14 words of memory.

Comment: @amon I haven't stated it explicitly, sry for that. Though the context would should be sufficient to see that I'm comparing to a LinkedList. And it's called reference, not pointer btw. And the point with memory wasn't about whether the class is used via inheritance or not, but simply the fact that (nearly) unused `ArrayList`s are waisting quite a bit of memory.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to look like the semantic of the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). It is used to model recursive datastructures.

Comment: I won't downvote this, but this is why I _**really**_ hate the GoF book. It's a bleedin' tree! Why did we need to invent the term "composite pattern" to describe a tree?

Comment: Though the Java example there uses the same private-children-list [Robert Harvey's answer](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/335213/26856) does.

Comment: @DavidArno I believe it's the whole polymorphic-node aspect that defines it as "composite pattern", the usage of a tree data structure is just part of it.

Comment: Yeah, the inheritance isn't being used to describe a tree; composition is doing that.  And the inheritance being used *isn't self-referential.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I disagree (with both your comments to your answer and here). `public class Node extends ArrayList<Node> { public string Item; }` is the inheritance version of your answer. Yours is simpler to reason, but both achieve the some thing: they define non-binary trees.

Comment: @DavidArno: I never said it wouldn't work, I just said that it's probably not ideal.

Comment: @DavidArno it's not about feelings and taste here, but it's about facts. A tree is made of nodes and every node has potential children.  A given node is a leaf node only at a given moment in time.  In a composite, a leaf node is leaf by construction, and its nature won't change.

Comment: @Christophe, oh well if we want to do facts: (a) I wrote my first leaf/branch union structure in C, 30ish years ago, long before the term "composite pattern" was coined and we called it a tree and (b) neither the OP's example or Robert's follow the UML for the "composite pattern", they are both " made of nodes and every node has potential children". But I'm still not going to downvote this answer...

Comment: @Christophe I agree on the point that dynamic semantical mutation is that what the composite tries to avoid.

Comment: @oopexpert Maybe rephrase "really looks like" with "seems to look like".  Reading OP's question, I first thought he had strong arguments that justify this construct in the frame of a more general design intent.  But after his exchange with Robert, it turned out to be only an implementation shortcut.

Comment: Due to democracy and social responsibility I reformulated it... I was really thinking about to "flag" my own answer...

Comment: @DavidArno Composition is very much *not* a tree. Both have *some* similarities, but they are also vastly different in other aspects. Composition - if done right - is much more powerful then a tree. Yes, the composite pattern in GoF is crap, because they use C++ and thus can't use C# or Java features that make the composite pattern much, much more elegant (knowing types at runtime).

Comment: @DavidArno Please read the GoF book first. The composite pattern is absolutely a tree. The point of the pattern is not that we have a new fancy word for trees, but to make it easier to use tree structures – client code is not supposed to traverse them. The example in the Design Patterns book is a GUI framework where each widget can `Draw()` itself. If a widget contains other widgets, drawing the parent will also cause all children to be drawn: actions on the tree root are distributed over the whole tree, so that it can be handled as a single composite item, not a conglomerate of many things.