# Stack extending LinkedList. A violation of Liskov Substitution Principle?

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, solid, liskov-substitution

A class LinkedList exists with functions such as add_first(), add_last(), add_after(), remove_first(), remove_last() and remove()

Now there is a class Stack that provides functionalities such as push(), pop(), peek() or top(), and to implement these methods it extends the LinkedList class methods. Is this a violation of Liskov Substitution Principle?

For example, consider the case add_after() to add a node at the nth position of a Linked List. This can be done in the base class but not in the Stack class. Are postconditions being weakened here or do you modify the add_after() method to add to the top of the Stack?

Also, if not a violation, is this bad design? And how would you implement the Stack functionality using the LinkedList class?

Comment: The question [What would be the disadvantage to defining a class as a subclass of a list of itself?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/335210/60357) asks about a slightly different problem, but most of the answers apply here as well: you're better of creating a Stack with a List as private member rather than inheriting from List.

Comment: Yes this is a bad design since it will prevent you changing the internal representation of the stack to something other than a linked list (e.g. an array). You're also exposing operations which stacks do not usually support.  Use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Do you want to extend `LinkedList`? You may want to heed the advice of a certain Joshua Bloch (who played a major role in designing the Java collections framework) when he said "Prefer composition over inheritance" - Maybe have a `LinkedList` inside your stack class, but not actually extend it?

Comment: I'd say it cannot satisfy the Liskov substitution principle, because "a stack is a kind of linked list" is not a true statement. "Stack" is really an interface (I mean conceptually, not the Java construct). A stack can be _implemented_ with a linked list. Like others have said, you would use a private data member of type `LinkedList` that does the heavy lifting behind the scenes (composition). That way users of your code can't accidentally use a Stack where they needed a List or vice versa.

Comment: It seems what would be saner would be the opposite. If I were doing this I would probably have a linked list class implement a "stack" interface as its fully capable of doing so. Otherwise this is the wrong way around as a stack is a concept, a linked list is an implementation which can act as a stack among other things.

Comment: In Java, the `Stack` extends `Vector` (a synchronized array list). People like Joshua Bloch have noted some of the challenges this leads to.

Answer (score 33):

> Now there is a class Stack that provides functionalities such as push(), pop(), peek() or top(), and to implement these methods it extends the LinkedList class methods. Is this a violation of Liskov Substitution Principle?

No. It is perfectly fine to add methods in a subtype.

> For example, consider the case add_after() to add a node at the nth position of a Linked List. This can be done in the base class but not in the Stack class.

This *is* a violation of the LSP. The LSP says that instances of a subtype must be substitutable for instances of a supertype without changing the desirable properties of a program. If a subtype removes a method, then any code that calls that method will crash (or get a `NoMethodError` exception, or something along those lines). Clearly, "not crashing" is a desirable property.

> Are postconditions being weakened here or do you modify the add_after() method to add to the top of the Stack?

Modifying the `add_after()` method in this way is a violation of the History Rule (the most important of the rules!) and thus doesn't help fixing the violation of the LSP.

> And how would you implement the Stack functionality using the LinkedList class?

By using composition.

NOTE: Everything I wrote above *only* applies to languages which confuse subtyping and subclassing! The LSP is about *subtyping*, not subclassing. In a language which does not confuse the two, it would be perfectly acceptable to make `Stack` a subclass of `LinkedList`, as long as you do not make it a *subtype* of `LinkedList`.

Comment: What is the History Rule? I failed to find it in the internet.

Comment: When manipulating an object of a subtype, and observing it through methods of the supertype, it must be impossible to observe a history that could not also be observed with an object of the supertype. This rule ist the one that makes the LSP applicable to non-functional languages. All the other stuff had already been known long before that. The pre- and postcondition rules are reformulations of the co- and contravariance rules for function types. The history rule makes all of this applicable to mutable data. Without it, the LSP would only be useful for purely functional languages.

Comment: I think the explanation in the Wikipedia article is reasonably good: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle But as always, you should really read the original source.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: While I would think it reasonable for types to include in their contract guarantees about what "history" will or will not be observed, I don't think that it should be necessary that every supertype be capable of producing every sequence of observations that might be possible on an object of the subtype--merely that the supertype document the possibility that consumers of the supertype might observe such sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything was already addressed by Jörg W Mittag, I just elaborate a bit on the following part:

> Are postconditions being weakened here or do you modify the
>   add_after() method to add to the top of the Stack?

Basically, when there is a question whether some hierarchy violates LSP, it depends on what contract you pose. So, what contract does `add_after` have? If it sounds, however crazy, like "Add a node at the n-th position or at the top", than you're fine, the post-condition is met, LSP is not violated. Otherwise it's an LSP violation.